# Putting regex inside the Gmail.search function. Google Apps Script

Tags: regex, google-apps-script, gmail

I have an automation script that handles emails with a particular subject. It was working for a while, but now there is a second type of email that gets the same label and has a very similar subject. The subject I want is `RITM12345 Approval Request` where `12345` can be any number. The subject I don't want is `CHG12345 Approval Request` where `12345` can be any number.

I wanted to initially put a regular expression inside the `GmailApp.search` function, but the regex is taken as a literal string. I can't seem to find any documentation on how to filter this during the email search. I tried `GmailApp.search('subject:"Approval Request"-CHG')`, but this does not work because the rest of the `CHG` string has numbers appended to it.

Currently, I am doing this:

```
  var threadSubject = /RITM([0-9]+) Approval Request/;      
  var threads = GmailApp.search('from:"email.com" is:unread subject: "Approval Request" label:"Approval Request"', 0,1);

  if (threads.length > 0) {
    for (var i=0; i < 1; i++) {
      var messages = GmailApp.getMessagesForThread(threads[i]);
        for (var j=0; j < messages.length; j++ ) {
          var message = threads[i].getMessages()[j];                        
          var subject = message.getSubject();              
        }
        if (subject.match(threadSubject)) { 
          do automation code here if it matches my regex, then mark thread as read
        }
```

The code re-runs in a minute and finds next unread message

The inherent problem with this code is that I only want to find unread messages with the desired subject. Currently, this code is only locating the unread `CHG12345 Approval Request` thread over and over again (since it is the first thread found). Marking this unwanted thread read or changing this unwanted threads label are also not an option.

Also, one other thing to note. I am only grabbing one email at a time in my loop and the script triggers every minute. This is done for logging reasons and I was also getting bugs when the script would try to handle 20+ emails all at once

Answer (score 2):

Can you try something like this?

```
var threads = GmailApp.search('from:"email.com" is:unread subject: "Approval Request" label:"Approval Request"'); // remove 0 and 1

threads.forEach(function (t) {
  if (t.getFirstMessageSubject().match(/RITM\d+/) {
    toDoWithCorrectMessage(t);
  }
});
```

I've successfully used this code

```
function myFunction() {
  var threads = GmailApp.search('from: "newsletter@example.com"');
  Logger.log(threads.length);
  var counter = 0;
  threads.forEach(function (t) {
    if (t.getFirstMessageSubject().match("50%")) {
       counter++;
     }
  });
  Logger.log(counter);  
}
```

to search from a daily newsletter all the mail with `"50%"`. This is the result:

```
[17-10-26 19:25:32:914 CEST] 214.0
[17-10-26 19:26:01:963 CEST] 3.0
```

32 seconds to run through 214 mails. Do you have more mails?

With search parameter as `'is: unread'` only:

```
[17-10-26 10:30:56:822 PDT] 500.0
[17-10-26 10:32:01:373 PDT] 4.0
```

if the search is repeated it is actually cached, thus it is really faster (here a third test with again all unread email)

```
[17-10-26 20:04:03:824 CEST] Start
[17-10-26 20:04:04:681 CEST] 500.0
[17-10-26 20:05:11:128 CEST] 4.0
```

Comment: This would loop through all my unread messages correct? I'm hoping to try and avoid that.

Comment: just put in the query a limit of how many back it should go in the query. But with your search call in your original code you will get only one thread.

Comment: Yeah, I think I have to unfortunately come to that compromise. I mentioned it in the thread of the other answer about handling 5 emails at a time and hoping my end user deals with the unwanted threads before they stack up to 5. Too bad I can't stick that regex  GmailApp.search

Comment: Regexp in Gmail search simply does not exist. They require too much computational power from the server.

Comment: The 0, 1 in your code do not apply to email, they refer to threads.

Comment: Right, I also have this though `for (var i=0; i < 1; i++) `

Comment: Written in that way you get **only one thread** nothing more. Thus it is impossible (if the first one is a CHG) to get even one RITM

Comment: Right, that is why I wanted it in the search function. I guess I'll loop 5 times and hope the end user doesn't let 5 of them stack their way to the top.

Comment: Sorry, I really don't understand your approach.

Answer (score 2):

I tried on my email and it works pretty well for me.  I was surprised how long it takes to run.

```
function getMyMessages() 
{      
  var threads = GmailApp.search('from:"email.com" subject:"Approval Request"');//gets Approval Requests
  var s='';
  for(var i=0;i<threads.length;i++)
  {
     var messages = GmailApp.getMessagesForThread(threads[i])
     for (var j=0; j<messages.length;j++) 
     {
       if(messages[j].isUnread())
       {   
         var message=messages[j].getBody()
         var subject=messages[j].getSubject();
         var from=messages[j].getFrom();
         var to=messages[j].getTo();
         if(subject.match(/RITM\d+/))//requires RITM in the subject or it won't be displayed
         {   
           s+=Utilities.formatString('<br />From: %s<br />To: %s<br />Subject: %s<br />Message: %s<br /><hr width="100%">', from,to,subject,message);
           messages[j].markRead();//if found it marks as read
         }
       }
     } 
  }
  var ui=HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(s).setWidth(1000);
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModelessDialog(ui, 'My Messages');//displays messages that pass the filter.
}
```

Comment: I'm trying to avoid looping through all my threads due to that very reason. I was getting some bugs such as threading, missed messages, timeouts and something else I can't remember. That is why I was hoping there was a possibility to have the regex be part of the GmailApp.search part and handle 1 email per minute.

Comment: I don't see any way to make it part of the gmail search.  That's actually something I was disappointed with when I first start using Google Mail.

Comment: Your code functions the same as mine mostly, but I just limit it to 1 email in my first `for` loop. Perhaps I limit it to 5 and hope the end user handles the unwanted emails before they stack up to 5 in a row. I think they are rare.

Comment: Yeh. I probably don't get as many emails as you so I'm not as concerned with the time that it takes to loop through them all.  However, I find it rather neat to filter them with regex.